# How to make dependable attributes in configurable products magento2?

Tags: magento2

I'm making a configurable product in which I have two dependable attributes i.e color and size. The issue is I am not getting how to give both the attribute different prices and make the size dependable on the size,

For instance :
color : red, blue
Size : s,xl,2xl,3xl

Iwant size dependent on the size it is done but how to give the red attribute to price $30 and blue to $40, and further s = $20, xl=$30, make sense ?

So can any one help me, I'm also digging the google.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have two dropdowns size and framing, 

size :
s,xl,2xl

Framing: 
Paper,cotton,poly.

So i what want, if i select size : s then i dont want to display paper option, like this if i select 2xl then i didn't want to show cotton in framing dropdown make sense ?

And also for the size i have different prices and also for framings, so the price is also dependent on both of them.